# tigger(click) with value

Tags: jquery, click

Hi I need to send a value when i tigger a click.

What I have is a script that turns select box into a div drop down. and it removes the option and replaces it with a hidden input.

The way the script works is when a user clicks the div it drop down a box with other divs in it, and each div as its own val="{id}" i need to be able to do a trigger click function and fake that a user has clicked one of these divs.

Here is the jQuery code that the click uses.

```
list.children(".option").click(function() {
            html.children("input[name='" + sName + "']").val($(this).attr("val"));
            fetch(104,"task=updateuserstatus&userid="+userid+"&status="+$(this).attr("val"));
            html.children(".label").html($(this).html());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

once you register a jQuery click function you can call it anytime, in a number ways.  `$('selector').click();` will activate all jQUery registered events, and the regular window.click event for the object.  `$('selector').triggerHandler('click');` will fire just the jQuery registered click handlers.

Is that what you wanted? or did you want to trigger a click in the newly inserted inputs?

--edit --

```
<script type='text\javascript'>
$(document).ready(
  var list = $('something');
  $('.option', list).each(function(index, htmlElem){
     //bind to the click event
     // $(this).attr('val') becomes event.data
    // third param is your actual function as before
    $(this).bind('click', {"whatever": $(this).attr('val')}, function(event){
//tadaah!
  alert('hello :' + event.data.whatever);
//if you wanted to actually register a click event down here for the input, let me know
     html.children("input[name='" + sName + "']").val($(this).attr("val"));
     fetch(104,"task=updateuserstatus&userid="+userid+"&status="+$(this).attr("val"));
     html.children(".label").html($(this).html());
    });
  });
);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I send a val with it

Comment: Sorry no, I want to know how to send a value with with trigger

Comment: i'm going drinking, let me know if you wanted the click event on the input and I can post tomorrow.  It will take the 'bind' idea and just move it down into this html stuff you're doing.  which, what are you doing in the  html.stuff ?

Comment: feel free to change `$('.option',list)`  to your original `list.children(".option")` if my code selects too many options!

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a click quite easily:

```
$('#element').click();
```